# Custom selector (with extra params) in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

How to define action with extra param in UIBarButtonItem?

I need to pass CNContactViewController object to buttonActionMethod:

```
class ContactHelper { 

    public static func showContact(controller: UIViewController, contactViewControllerDelegate: CNContactViewControllerDelegate,

                                   contact: CNContact) {

        let contactController = CNContactViewController.init(for: contact)

        contactController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =

            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.cancel, target: self,

                          action: #selector(ContactHelper.buttonAction))

        contactController.delegate = contactViewControllerDelegate

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactController)

        controller.present(navigationController, animated: false)

    }

    private static func buttonAction(sender: ContactButton) {
        // need to pass contactController from showContact function
        contactController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you can't use an extra parameter here!

Comment: @Mannopson, 
what to do if the action requires an additional parameter?

Comment: Update your question with more specific details about what extra data you need and where it comes from.

Comment: @rmaddy, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the signature of action methods. The given API enforces a specific set of allowed parameters. In this case, the only allowed parameter is the button.

The proper solution is to refactor your ContactHelper class to use instance methods and instance properties to store state instead of making everything static.

Another (possibly better) solution to is extend `CNContactViewController` to add the additional functionality instead of creating this helper class.